# Can't type any letters or numbers in text inputs in fullscreen mode on webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, keyboard-events

After switching to fullscreen mode (tested on chrome and safari), I can't type any letters or numbers in text inputs, but I still can enter special characters like `*¨%£` but no simple letters...

The code is really simple :

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="fullScreen">LAUNCH FULLSCREEN</button>
<input type="text" />
```

JS

```
function launchFullScreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  }
}

document.getElementById("fullScreen").addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
  launchFullScreen(document.documentElement);
}, false);
```

As Jan Dvorak mentioned, the problem appears only when using the js function, the bug doesn't appears when using the browser build-in fullscreen button/shortcut

See it in action :

http://jsfiddle.net/QwqT7/show/

UPDATE 2 :

Just tested on Firefox for mac, no problems in fullscreen mode.
It seems that the problem is webkit only.

Comment: confirmed, weird. Looks like a bug. http://jsfiddle.net/QwqT7/show/

Comment: It only happens if I use the button to go fullscreen, though. It works correctly when doing `F11`

Comment: you're right, I will update the question and add your jsfiddle, thanks

Comment: Try setting some other element fullscreen. Say, `document.body`

Comment: @JanDvorak I tried with document.body and a div: same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mozilla note](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/) says:

> For security reasons, most keyboard inputs have been blocked in the fullscreen mode. However, in Google Chrome you can request keyboard support by calling the method with a flag...

Comment: Thanks it helped me to solve the problem in Chrome at least. I posted my code, it can helps somebody else.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a perfect solution, but at least it will allow Chrome to responds to keyboard commands and let Safari use the fullscreen mode without key inputs as a fallback.

```
function launchFullScreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT)){
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!document.webkitCurrentFullScreenElement && element.webkitRequestFullScreen()) {
      element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
  },100);
}
```